# Unable to run client server program on the server getting error : socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use

Tags: php, sockets

I have created a client and server programs using socket it is working perfectly on the localhost but when i upload it to the server through cpanel it does not work properly and it gives following error. The main thing is some times both of the program works on the server.
I am new to socket programming and seen some of the related posts on stackoverflow but was unable to found exact solution.

```
Client: Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [111]: Connection refused in .../client.php on line 10
Could not connect to server

Server:Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in ..server.php on line 10
Could not bind to socket
```

Client.php

```
<?php
// where is the socket server?
$host    = "XX.XX.XXX.XX";
$port    = 25763;
$message = "Hello Server This is the first message to the server";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// connect to server
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not connect to server\n");  
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read ($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :".$result;
// close socket
socket_close($socket);
    // print result to browser
?>
```

Server.php

```
<?php
// set some variables
$host = "XX.XX.XXX.XX";
$port = 25763;
// don't timeout!
set_time_limit(0);
// create socket
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
// bind socket to port
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die("Could not bind to socket\n");
// start listening for connections
$result = socket_listen($socket, 3) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");

// accept incoming connections
// spawn another socket to handle communication
$spawn = socket_accept($socket) or die("Could not accept incoming connection\n");
// read client input
$input = socket_read($spawn, 1024) or die("Could not read input\n");
// clean up input string
$input = trim($input);
echo "Client Message : ".$input;
// reverse client input and send back
$output = strrev($input) . "\n";
echo $spawn;
socket_write($spawn, $output, strlen ($output)) or die("Could not write output\n");
// close sockets
socket_close($spawn);
socket_close($socket);
?>
```

Comment: What kind of server did you upload this to?

Comment: Is it shared? Do you have a dedicated IP?

Comment: This program is working properly on localhost but sometimes it work properly on server also, It is shared.

Comment: How are you running it?

Comment: @user3809096 That may very well be the problem.  As far as I'm aware, you need a dedicated IP for your code to properly work, and you would need to look into buying a port in such a regard.  Not all ports are made free by the host.  I don't know enough about the subject, so I'll just let someone more knowledgeable answer instead, and vote that up.

Comment: Firstly i start the server and then client the client passes the message to the server and server after reversing that string pass it to client to display. I have noted that on the server after 3-4 minutes when i run the server program it runs only for one time and give response properly but after stopping then if i want it to run it gives the above message, then i have to wait for some time and again run the server after few minutes.. whats the problem behind that i am not able to understand please help to solve it ....

Comment: Thanks Daedalus, Please let me know some more info related to my question if you get....

Comment: possible duplicate of [unable to bind address \[0\]: php error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3377927/unable-to-bind-address-0-php-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the server you might like to set option `SO_REUSEADDR` on the freshly created socket using [`socket_set_opt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-set-option.php).

For code how to do this please see the example section on manual page linked above.